# Can graphics created with Wolfram Mathematica be freely used and distributed?

Tags: writing, software

This is just a simple question. I would like to know if one can use graphics generated by Mathematica (for example, plots) in one's paper and then upload that paper anywhere on the internet.

I would also like to know if one can freely use and upload the graphics alone (for example, in PDF or JPG format) anywhere on the internet.

Comment: There may be some issues with Wolfram Alpha, which is different from Wolfram Mathematica. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Alpha#Copyright_claims Apparently they try to claim authorship and copyright of Wolfram Alpha's output.

Comment: @BenCrowell But this doesn't affect Wolfram Mathematica, does it?

Comment: *But this doesn't affect Wolfram Mathematica, does it?* eykanal's answer linked to the license, which would be the authoritative source of information.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with making public an image created with Mathematica; that's the whole point of the software. The [license](http://www.wolfram.com/legal/agreements/wolfram-mathematica.html) restricts your rights regarding what you can do with the software package itself (no copying, reverse-engineering, selling, etc), but not the content you produce using the software. If that was the case, no one could use the software to do anything.

You may, however, be restricted by the journal to which you submitted your article. The publication holds all rights to your article, including the figures. You may retain some rights to using the images in your own work (e.g., presentations); you'd have to check with your specific journal.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and this is not a legal advice, blabla.

Your software license type generally determine what kind of use of the software is allowed: e.g educational license allow only educational use, therefore you cannot make figure eg. for a research paper. Also, if you have some academic license, it often restrict any for-profit use, i.e. you cannot make a figure and sell it to someone or upload it to a stock photo database.